# How to parse json, using org-json libraries?

Tags: java, json, parsing

Looking for org-json solutions only please **

Suppose you deal with a structure, as follows.

Using `json-org`, how can i get an array of Tests, if this entire json is represented in a `String` s?

Using Google's gson, it's easy to do by testing what type given object is ... i am missing something simple here with `json-org` libraries

```
{
   "Groups":{
      "Test":[
         {
            "Test Number":123456,
            "Channel":"TEST",
            "environment":"A",
            "output event":[
               {
                  "description":"very good description",
                  "value":123,
                  "active":true
               },
               {
                  "description":"another very good description",
                  "value":456,
                  "active":true
               }
            ],
            "active":true,
            "instrument":"ABC"
         },
         {
            "Test Number":547985,
            "Channel":"some new channel",
            "environment":"B",
            "output event":[
               {
                  "description":"reject",
                  "value":123,
                  "active":true
               },
               {
                  "description":"ack",
                  "value":456,
                  "active":true
               }
            ],
            "active":true,
            "instrument":"XYZ"
         }
      ],
      "name":"A clever name",
      "active":true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It so happens i got it before someone else had a chance to help. In case someone else has similar question, i am posting an answer below:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(s);

JSONArray arrayOfTests = (JSONArray) ((JSONObject) o.get("Groups")).get("Test");

for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfTests.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(arrayOfTests.get(i));
}
```

Comment: JSONObject o = new JSONObject(s);                                                In this line  i got eroor. "The constructor JSONObject is undefined".

Comment: What is "s" in your case? Should be String object, i believe